# where does the business logic live when using a state pattern ?

Tags: c#, java, state-pattern

IS it the wrapper object ? or the state object itself ?

can I please see some examples ?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you'll have business logic on state change. This may include "state_entered" triggers and "state_leave" triggers.

You may want "state_idle" triggers on the chance a state can enter itself.

Examples will require code from your end to base it off of.

Answer (score 0):

In the state pattern the business logic is concerned with transitions from one state to the next. You have two choices and both are equally valid.

The state change logic may live in the state objects themselves, making it quite easy to add new state objects to the system but coupling the sub classes more tightly.

Or the state change logic may reside in the context. Therefore the states themselves are not aware of each other. Addition of new states will require modification of the context.

There are several good resources for patterns online that may give you good examples. For instance [this site](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state). Or [this one](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx) with specific c# examples.

Answer (score -2):

Please be more specific with your question since the answer may depend on the concrete use case. However, usually I'd expect the states to implement a common internal interface that is used by the wrapper object which in turn fulfils a sort of public interface. So the business logic would be split up and thereby basically placed  in both types.